# How send a comment in a github pullRequest from jenkins/jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, comments, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

I use the organization plugin to build the pullRequest of my github project. 
During this build, I want to send a custom comment with some metric of the project to the github pullRequest.

How can I do it?

Comment: Execute some script that calls the GitHub API. I'm not aware of any Jenkins plugin that provides a pipeline step for this (which would be super awesome).

Comment: Or directly call it through the pipeline groovy code...

Comment: @StephenKing 
If anyone find the name of the plugin, or give me a pice of code, I will count-it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeverMind, I found : (you need to install the http Request plugin)

```
        def SHA1 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim()
        def body="""{
                 "body": "Nice change",
                 "commit_id": "$SHA1",
                 "path": "/",
                 "position": 0
           }"""


        httpRequest authentication: '${yourCredential}', httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: body,  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/${yourOrga}/${yourRepo}/issues/${pullRequestNumber}/comments'
```

Comment: could you elaborate about how you can get the pull request number and what kind of credentials you need?

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed to comment, but elaborating on previous answer:

```
httpRequest authentication: '${yourCredential}', httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: body,  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/${yourOrga}/${yourRepo}/issues/${pullRequestNumber}/comments'
```

$yourcredential is a name that should match a credential of type Username and password.  In github you should create a token and use this.

in a pullrequest you will usually will get the url (Genericwebhook) to the issue where you can post a comment as part of the webhook payload.